# Типы сущностей в Android приложении

Tags: android, архитектура, model, pojo

Мой вопрос связан с сущностями, которые хранят данные, в Android приложении. Изначально в моем проекте был пакет Models, который содержал все классы, с которыми работало приложение. Эти классы использовались как объекты, возвращаемые от запросов к api (POJO), так и использовались в самом интерфейсе приложения, а именно в RecyclerView и для этого они имплементировали интерфейс Item, которые был нужен для определения какой тип layout использовать. Из-за того что происходило смешивание предназначения классов, я решил сделать два пакета: POJO и Item. В пакете Pojo хранились классы, которые возвращались от Api, а в пакете Item классы, которые использовались в RecyclerView. Эти пакеты содержали дублирующие классы, при этом не все используемые объекты были в пакете Item, так как они не использовались в списках и получалось так, что где-то использовались классы из пакета item, а где то из pojo, кроме того приходилось делать методы для конвертирования объектов. Мне это не нравится и я бы хотел узнать как правильно разделить классы и как их потом использовать. Сейчас у меня есть идея сделать пакет pojo, который содержит классы для api и сделать пакет Model, которые будет содержать объекты, которые используются только в интерфейсе приложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю стоит начать с того, что нет никакого "Правильно". Все зависит от задач и ваших потребностей.

Если у вас банковское приложение то вероятно у вас будет огромное количество сущностей которые будут поделены по разным категориям и использоваться в разных местах.

Если же вы пишете калькулятор для курсовой то вам скорее всего не понадобится ничего разделять.

Чаще всего из делят на типы: Network, Local и UI.

1. Network - это ваши POJO которые вы получаете от сервера в том виде в котором отдает их вам сервер.
2. Local - это модели с которыми работает ваше приложение. Обычно это модель полученная от сервера адаптированная под ваши нужды.
   Таким образом вы будете всегда иметь исходную модель и отдельную модель для работы внутри приложения. И если на серваке что-то изменится, то вам по сути придется изменить только мапперы.
   Например:

   - Вы можете использовать не все поля которые вам отдает сервер и вы не хотите их видеть в своей модели.
   - Или вы хотите полученную от сервера модель разбить на несколько своих более мелких которые впоследствии будут использоваться раздельно.
   - Или вы хотите добавить новые методы или логику set/get методов.
3. UI модели используются реже. Но эти модели создаются для разделения логики которая работает внутри приложения и видна пользователю.

   - Например вам для отображения списка надо объеденить 2+ модели в одну.
   - Для того чтоб в какой-то элемент UI не отправлять больше данных чем необходимо отобразить пользователю.
   - Для того чтоб обобщить группу каких-то моделей под одним интерфейсом для использования в какой-то View (RecycleView с множественными ViewHolder).

Можно придумать и другие разделения. Здесь нет какой-то библии. Всегда надо отталкиваться от ваших потребностей.